# How to test AND in flags?

Tags: php, constants, bitwise-operators, flags, bitwise-and

I'm trying to determine if a value represents a combination of valid flags.

Here's some test code:

```
$permissions = [2, 4, 16, 1024];

$test = 8; // single value - ok
$test = 4 | 8 | 2048; // OR - ok  
$test = 4 | 16; // OR - ok
$test = 4 & 8; // AND - ok
$test = 4 & 16; // AND - fails :(

foreach($permissions as $perm){
  if($test & $perm){
    print 'ok!';
    break;
  }  
}
```

As you can see it fails when I try to see if the array contains two specific flags. Is there any way I can make AND work?

```
$test = 4 & 16; // should return true because both values are in the array
```

Answer (score 1):

try `&&` in `if($test & $perm){`